# Allowing emails on iptables

Tags: linux, networking, email, iptables, smtp

I am trying to configure my iptables firewall (currently rejecting all traffic) to allow emails traffic. For SMTP port 465 is used (SMTPS port), and for IMAP  it uses port 143. But whatever I try, I cannot get a connection to work. Here are my iptables rules:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 143 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I can easily get ssh connections to run with my other iptables rules, so I must be missing something here. Any ideas?

Comment: Are these rules for an e-mail server? You don't need the `INPUT` chain rules for a client. Default `DROP` policy for the `OUTPUT` chain are unnecessary for most desktop/client computers and often complicate things. Try changing the default policy to `ACCEPT` for the `OUTPUT`. Lastly, maybe there's something wrong with the server-side or your client configuration.

Comment: The rules are for my email client, not a server. I have deleted the OUTPUT rules specified above, and I have changed the default OUTPUT policy to accept. Still it does not work. If I remove all restrictions/iptables I can connect to the email server, so my client is configured correctly. It must be something related to the iptables that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all on OUTPUT chain you should have only ESTABLISHED and RELATED - to create stateful firewall without ports... and it all should work as you already allowed incoming ports.

Check this firewall script:

https://doittherightway.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/basic-bash-iptables-dmz-firewall-script/

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for pointing out my mistake in the output chain. That does however not solve my problem (neither does the link you posted).

Comment: You are trying to get email on box running iptables or box behind it?

Comment: I try to receive (and be able to send) emails from my iptables-firewalled computer. the iptables firewall does not allow any in/out connections except ssh (and email as soon as it works).

Comment: You are missing tcp/25 (smtp) in your OUTPUT chain... but encrypted mail should work though

Comment: I added an output chain for port 25 (-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT) but it still does not work (neither sendind nor receiving email)